# Git for windows setting different permissions on files in same repo

Tags: windows, git, file, permissions

I have a local repository on my host machine. I need to clone this repo from the host machine to a vm running debian. Folders are shared, files are accessible.

But git seems to set different permission for different parts of the repo.

So while most files have my windows user set to Full control, the individual files in ./.git/objects//* have just the SYSTEM/Admin/Administrator permissions and *not* my windows user. Mind you, the folders in ./.git/objects/* have my windows user set, but the files within not.

Because of this git clone fails for these files. Is there a way to tell git to add my windows user to any file it creates?